# Find Distribution of Sum of Random Variables given only Joint Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

So if we have two random variables $X, Y$, with **unknown** distributions. Then we have a random variable $Z$, such that $Z=X+Y$.

Firstly, how do we find the CDF of $Z$, i.e. $F_Z(z)$, given the joint PDF of $X, Y$;

$$f_{XY}(x,y) \ \ \ \ \ for \ \ x, y > 0$$

Intuitively, as far as I can tell, the expression to find this is (hopefully):

$$F_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{z} \int_{0}^{z-x} f_{XY}(x,y) \  dy \ dx $$

Except I wasn't certain about whether this is the case, so I wanted to prove it. Therefore my real question is how to show this expression is correct?

Perhaps something along the lines of ?:

\begin{align} 
F_Z(z) & = P(Z \le z)       \\
       & = P(X + Y \le z)   \\
       ...???               \\
       ...???               \\
       & = P(Y \le z -x \ \ \ and \ \ \ X \le z)
\end{align}

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your formula for the CDF of $Z$ is correct. You wrote $F_Z(z) = P(X+Y \leq z)$. Can you express the last quantity in terms of the density?

Comment: @Michh I'm sorry, honestly, I've no clue. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\begin{align*} F_Z(z) &= P(X+Y \leq z) = E[\mathbf{1}_{X+Y \leq z}]\\
&= \int_{[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)} \mathbf{1}_{x+y \leq z} \; f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
 \end{align*}$$
using the following property of the density: $E[g(X,Y)] = \int_{[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)} g(x,y)\, f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$. Now notice that $\mathbf{1}_{x+y \leq z} = \mathbf{1}_{x \leq z} \mathbf{1}_{y \leq z - x}$, that is $x+y \leq z$ if and only if $x \leq z$ and $y \leq z - x$. So using Fubini's theorem, we get
$$
\begin{align*} F_Z(z) = \int_{[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)} \mathbf{1}_{x \leq z} \mathbf{1}_{y \leq z - x} \; f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y &= \int_{[0,\infty)} \mathbf{1}_{x \leq z} \left(\int_{[0,\infty)}\mathbf{1}_{y \leq z - x} \; f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right)\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^z \left(\int_0^{z-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}$$
which proves the result. Normally you would not have to go into as much detail and from the first equation above you could directly obtain the result.