# Distribution of the difference between two random variables given joint distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have two continuous random variables X and Y, where $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ denoting the expected value of X and Y, $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$ the respective standard variations, $\rho$ the coefficient of correlation, and $f(x,y)$ the joint p.d.f of X and Y for $x,y>0$.Then, I have a random variable Z such that Z=X-A*Y, where A is a positive constant. How do I find the p.d.f of Z?

Comment: The title mentions that you have the joint distribution of $X,Y$, so do you actually? How would you denote their joint cumulative distribution function for example?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The p.d.f. is $f(x,y)$ for $x,y>0$

Comment: To get started, for given $z$ sketch the region in the $xy$ plane where $x - Ay \leq z$. What is the total probability of that region based on your joint density?

Answer (score 1):

For continuous random vairables, it's easier to express their c.d.f.:

- Let $F_X$ be the c.d.f. of $X$,
- $F_Y$ be the c.d.f. of $Y$,
- $F_Z$ be the c.d.f of $Z$,
- and $F_{X,Y}$ be the joint c.d.f of $(X,Y)$.

Then the c.d.f of $Z$ will be

$$F_Z(x) = P(Z < x) = P(X-AY<x) \stackrel{(*)}{=} \\ \stackrel{(*)}{=} \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X < x+t, AY > t)dt = \\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X < x+t, Y > t/A)dt = \\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X<x+t)-P(X<x+t,Y<t/A)dt = \\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(x+t)-F_{X,Y}(x+t,t/A)dt$$

where in $(*)$ I used the [Law of total probablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

This is "calculatable". So from here, you can technically express $f_Z(x)$ with differentiation.

Generally, what I've done here is a variation of [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), which is used to calculate the c.d.f (or p.d.f) of $X+Y$.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it not expressed as a function of x and y?

Comment: Both sides are a function of $x$ in this case, but you can substitute $z$ as well, if that fits your liking.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this. Would it be possible to have something like this?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055990/find-distribution-of-sum-of-random-variables-given-only-joint-distribution

Comment: I rewrote it for your with $z$. Both sides depend on $z$, and nothing else, because we integrate out the right side by $t$.

$$F_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(z+t)-F_{X,Y}(z+t,t/A)dt$$

Which part would need to depend on $x$ or $y$?